# Windows Froms Centerscreen does'nt work anymore when I deploy my app on windows tablet

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I'm actually working on an app which will have to work on a Windows Tablet.
I have a weird issue which is pissing me of.
Only one of my forms does'nt want to respect de StartPosition.CenterScreen and start as shown on the image.

[Displaying Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgSWw.jpg)

I've searched tips and tricks but the fact is that it works on my PC so I don't understand what the problem is.

Here are some things I've found that didn't work :

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
this.Top = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - this.Height)/2;
this.Left = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - this.Width)/2;
```

Instead of

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

Then I've tried removing those two elements as I've shown during my searches

```
this.Text;
this.MaximumSize;
```

And I've put them on the loading event but it didn't work.

Finally I've tried this code in the calling form :

```
this.Hide();
FrmMain frm = new FrmMain(User, Centrale, Frequence);
frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
frm.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

But didn't work either.
So I require your help, and I only want the form to be centered no matter the way.

================================= UPDATE ==================================

I've found a way to fix my issue. Indeed, thanks to @HansPassant and @Anil, I've tried to change my screen resolution on my own PC, so I could run it with my debugger. After a few attempts, I've changed the AutoScale property even if there was the following message : Obsolete : "This property has been deprecated. Use the AutoScaleMode property instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202".

Well thanks for all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e

Comment: @HansPassant well thanks but it is not my problem here, my issue is about centerscreen not blurry font :/

Comment: I think @HansPassant want to say that resolution on your PC and tablet is different may that is the reason it is not in center

Comment: Also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456469/form-looks-different-on-another-computer and read about flow layout panel

Comment: Ok so I tried setting a lower resolution on my PC and you were right : now even on my PC it doesn't center my form. So do you have any idea about what I could change ?